# $PATH is driving me nuts

Tags: macos, path, homebrew, fish

OK, apologies if this is something dumb, but I'm running out of ideas.

**Goal:** prepend `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH`

**Problem:** `$PATH` won't do what I want or expect

**How I got here:** I want to start learning to program, so I'm getting comfortable messing around under the hood, but don't have a lot of experience. I installed the `fish` shell (because it's friendly!) using `homebrew` and set it as my default shell (under `system prefs>users & groups>advanced`). At some point, I ran `brew doctor` to see if my installs were all kosher, and it suggested I move `/usr/local/bin` to the front of `$PATH` so that I could use my installation of `git` rather than the system copy.  Fine - but between `path_helper` and `fish`, something was happening to `$PATH` that was out of my control, and I could never get the paths arranged in the right way.

**Environment:** OSX 10.8.2, upgraded from 10.7ish, with `xcode` and devtools installed, plus `x11`, `homebrew`, and `fish`

**More info:** I've set my user's default shell back to `bash`, and tried a variety of shells thru `terminal.app` - `bash`, `fish`, `sh`. I moved `/usr/local/bin` to the top of `/etc/paths` but it didn't change anything. I looked thru the various `config.fish` files and commented out stuff that might mess with $PATH, didn't help. I have the following files in `/etc/paths.d/`:

`./10-homebrew` containing `/usr/local/bin`

`./20-fish` containing `/usr/local/Cellar/fish/1.23.1/bin`

`./40-XQuartz` containing `/opt/X11/bin`

I added `set +x` to my `profile` and when I start `terminal.app` I get:

```
Last login: Mon Oct  1 13:31:06 on ttys000
+ '[' -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ']'
+ eval '/usr/libexec/path_helper -s'
++ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/fish/1.23.1/bin:/opt/X11/bin";
export PATH;
+ '[' /bin/bash '!=' no ']'
+ '[' -r /etc/bashrc ']'
+ . /etc/bashrc
++ '[' -z '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
++ PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
++ shopt -s checkwinsize
++ '[' Apple_Terminal == Apple_Terminal ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ PROMPT_COMMAND='update_terminal_cwd; '
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local 'SEARCH= '
++ local REPLACE=%20
++ local PWD_URL=file://Chriss-iMac.local/Users/c4
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://Chriss-iMac.local/Users/c4 
Chriss-iMac:~ c4$
```

So it looks like path_helper runs, but then running `echo $PATH` nets me `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So, it looks like `path_helper` isn't even doing what it's supposed to anymore?

I'm sure there is some well-defined behavior here that I don't understand, or I borked something while trying to fix it.  Please help!

Comment: note, I can get it to work for `fish` by creating `~/.config/fish/config.fish` with `set PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH` but I still have the issue of `path_helper` apparently  not working like it should, and `$PATH` thus being incomplete. Also still have the issue of different `$PATH` for scripts, apps started from the GUI, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Aaron for responding and for all those who answered other similar questions on the stackexchange sites. For posterity's sake, here is what I figured out:

1. `path_helper` is called from `/etc/profile`, by the syntax `eval '/usr/libexec/path_helper -s'` (where the apostrophes are actually backticks). Like a dummy, I didn't know how backticks worked, and so had changed them to quotes for some reason. This broke my `profile` from loading `path_helper`. Replaced the back-ticks and now it works like it should (of course).
2. using `set PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH` in my `~/.config/fish/profile.fish` ensures that I get the right order in my preferred shell, but as long as `path_helper` works it may be redundant.
3. For ensuring that the complete `$PATH` is available to scripts, GUI apps, etc., it appears to be a toss-up between `launchd.conf` and `environment.plist`... still researching that one.

Comment: I read just the other day (but I don't recall the source) that 10.8 no longer offers a surefire way to get a path visible to all apps. I remember in particular that environment.plist is no longer read; I am vaguely aware of launchd.conf, so that might work, but I think the article suggested it wouldn't.

Comment: more follow-up: it doesn't look like path_helper works at all in fish; it outputs either csh or bash syntax, both of which are incompatible. Instead, you can use ~/.config/fish/config.fish (the fish startup script) to cat /etc/paths.d/* and append them to $PATH. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: did you even read my answer? it's been there since four months before your follow-up

Answer (score 5):

**solution:**

choose if you want a system wide setting or an user config and edit the appropriate configuration file, don't use path_helper with fish.

**more**

fish doesn't source /etc/profile, for system wide and user config it'll read /etc/fish/config.fish and ~/.config/fish/config.fish respectively [1].

path_helper is meant for using for shells that source a system wide profile file (sh, csh and their derivates).
Since 10.7 path_helper seems to honor order in /etc/paths, AFAIR it didn't in 10.6 and that was harder to cope with.

If you really want to use path_helper with fish you'll need to parse its output since it'll only provide sh and csh syntax with *-s* and *-c* options.

Something like

```
/usr/libexec/path_helper -c | sed -e 's/setenv/set -x/' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/[";]//g'
```

should do the job:

[1] http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/index.html#initialization

Comment: Great! This is what I have now: `if status --is-login
    eval (/usr/libexec/path_helper -c | sed -e 's/setenv/set -x/' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/[";]//g')
end` - works fine here with fish 2 and Mac OS 10.8.3

Answer (score 3):

I have absolutely no idea about /etc/paths.d, path_helper, &c., all of which seem like excessive complications to me, but the following at the end of your ~/.bashrc should put you right:

```
 PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Aaron - `path_helper` is an OSX-specific utility that supposedly sets `$PATH` at login by reading from `/etc/paths` and then `/etc/paths.d/*`. Anyway, I understand your suggestion should fix me for `bash`, but I actually want it to work in `fish` (and consistently across the system, if that's not too much to expect).

Comment: Ah -- sorry about that. I'm not an OS X user myself, more's pity, but from a bit of Google-bashing it looks as though [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) Stack Overflow question might be more like what you're after -- that said, again, I'm not an OS X user myself, and only responded because a quick (read: careless) look at your question made me think you were only interested in bash, so take my advice here with several grains of salt. Hope it helps, all the same --